# Jest: expect mockFN.mock.calls.length.toBe vs toHaveBeenCalledTimes

Tags: jestjs

The jest mock functions docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) show them using the `.mock.calls.length` property for assertions about spies. What is the difference between

```
const myFunc = jest.fn()
myFunc();
expect(myFunc.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
```

and

```
 const myFunc = jest.fn()
 myFunc();
 expect(myFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

?

Is it just sugar? When should the user use the `mock` object?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, those matchers are sugar**, but, of course, they don't cover all the possible scenarios one may want to assert. If the user don't have on them what they need, they'll have to use the `.mock` property.

In jest docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions), this is clearly stated under the **Custom Matchers** title:

> Finally, in order to make it less demanding to assert how mock functions have been called, we've added some custom matcher functions for you:
>
> *** matcher function examples ***
>
> These matchers are sugar for common forms of inspecting the `.mock` property. You can always do this manually yourself if that's more to your taste or if you need to do something more specific.